# How to get the minimum value from an array

Tags: postgresql

If I have an array of ints, how can I get the min value out of the array?

The `min()` and `least()` functions won't work directly on the array.

for example if I have an array like below:

```
select 'a', array[1,2,3];
```

I want 'a', 1 as the results of my query.

I've tried `select 'a', min(array[1,2,3]);` and `select 'a', least(array[1,2,3]);`

Answer (score 2):

```
select 'a', min(t) from unnest(array[1,2,3]) as t;
 ?column? | min 
----------+-----
 a        |   1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install the [intarray](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html#id-1.11.7.29.7) extension to sort the array and then pick the first element:

```
select (sort(array[3,2,1], 'asc'))[1]
```

Alternatively you can write such a function:

```
create function array_min(p_input int[])
  returns int
as
$$
   select *
   from unnest(p_input) as x(v)
   order by x.v nulls last
   limit 1
$$
language sql
immutable;
```

For the corresponding implementation of `array_max()` you need to use an `order by ... desc`

Answer (score 0):

we can unnest the array, then group by the unique id, and use the min() function on that query to get the min for each unique row.

run the following queries one by one to see how it works.

```sql
SELECT
    'a' AS id,
    array [1,2,3] AS the_array;

SELECT
    id,
    unnest(the_array) unnested_array
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            'a' id,
            array [1,2,3] AS the_array
    ) AS src;

SELECT
    id,
    min(unnested_array) AS min
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            id,
            unnest(the_array) unnested_array
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    'a' id,
                    array [1,2,3] AS the_array
            ) AS src
    ) AS subquery
GROUP BY
    id;
```

Answer (score 0):

[`LEAST()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST) is only good for a *small*, *known* number of array elements, allowing us to spell it out like this:

```
SELECT LEAST(arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]);
```

Else look to the answers of Adrian and a_horse.